# awk and gawk decimal integer comparison fails some time

Tags: awk, integer, compare, precision

I've written an AWK script to scan a check image log file (ASCII characters sent to laser or dot-matrix printer to print on preprinted check forms) kept with tee /tmp/$$.print for every check run. The goal is to add up the check tab invoice / discount values and compare to the dollar and cents and check amount printed on the check body. The script work as desired but fails unexpectedly where I can see no reason for the failure.  Out of 750 check images processed, 37 checks are unexpectedly being included in the collected list of checks where the sum of the check-tab invoices does not equal the amount of the check with nine checks found with actual differences:

```
37 /tmp/eq_check
   Check #  62110   04/07/2022   Sum tab    2240.45 Check amount 2240.45
   Check #  62131   04/07/2022   Sum tab    2099.22 Check amount 2099.22
   Check #  62134   04/07/2022   Sum tab    5124.40 Check amount 5124.40
   Check #  63143   04/14/2022   Sum tab     536.58 Check amount  536.58
   Check #  63148   04/14/2022   Sum tab    2354.18 Check amount 2354.18
   Check #  63155   04/28/2022   Sum tab    1276.55 Check amount 1276.55
...
   Check #  75161   12/09/2022   Sum tab     614.41 Check amount  614.41
   Check #  75172   12/09/2022   Sum tab   17445.24 Check amount 17445.24
   Check #  75176   12/09/2022   Sum tab    1194.85 Check amount 1194.85
   Check #  75179   12/09/2022   Sum tab     264.10 Check amount  264.10
9 /tmp/neq_check
   Check #  62122   04/07/2022   Sum tab     366.24 Check amount  150.00
   Check #  63199   05/10/2022   Sum tab   22310.65 Check amount 21274.66
   Check #  63268   06/09/2022   Sum tab   36086.37 Check amount 35918.21
   Check #  63310   06/30/2022   Sum tab   16841.02 Check amount 14652.00
   Check #  63429   09/07/2022   Sum tab    5955.87 Check amount 5707.53
   Check #  63449   09/12/2022   Sum tab 947268177.91 Check amount 28064.91
   Check #  75010   09/26/2022   Sum tab     562.82 Check amount  314.48
   Check #  75054   10/21/2022   Sum tab   10052.77 Check amount 9804.43
   Check #  75113   11/10/2022   Sum tab   19821.61 Check amount 7381.69
```

After I composed this post, It occurs to me to try changing the test for not equal to

if ( ( tab_total - pcheck_amt) != 0 ) to see if that works

Nope, same 37 false positives and 9 positives.

here is a test check:

```
# cat check63282

  99820989      20220616       326.10
  Discount                      -3.26




                                                     63282  06/21/2022 MU



                                                                      $322.84
  Three Hundred Twenty Two Dollars and 84 Cents********************************

#
```

Here is the code that is failing:

```
# upper tab example
#  947897461     20221024        76.00   947992349       20221031      1161.30
#  Discount                      -1.52   Discount                       -23.23
#  947897457.     20221024     6754.59   94793360        20221029      5731.54
#  Discount                    -135.09   Discount                      -114.63
#  SHIP & DEBIT  20221027   -25,866.38   947973361       20221029     1,386.00
#  947945737     20221027    28,325.70   Discount                       -27.72
#  Discount                    -566.51   947973365       20221029       312.00
#  947945740     20221027       404.00   Discount                        -6.24
#
#
#
# Check body example
#                                                     63449  09/12/2022 BM
#
#
#
#                                                                   $28,064.91
#  Twenty Eight Thousand  Sixty Four Dollars and 91 Cents***********************
#
# index(s,t)
#        Returns the position in string s where string t first
#        occurs, or 0 if it does not occur at all.

BEGIN{ tab_total = 0  }
{
     gsub(/,/, "")      # strip NN,NNN.NN -> NNNNN.NN
     gsub(/\$/, "")     # strip   $NNN.NN ->   NNN.NN
     gsub(/^M/, "")     # strip DOS line ending
     # Find a line with decimal point
     a= index($0,".")
            if ( a > 0 && a < 50 ) {
               for( i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                  b = index($i,".")
                  if( b > 0 ) {
                      tab_total+= ($i * 100)
                  }
               }

            }
     # Find the date line
     c= index($0,"/")
     if ( c > 50 ) {
        check_num = $1
        check_date = $2
        if( NF > 2 ) who_to = $3
     }
     # Find the printed check amount
     if ( a > 50  ) {
         pcheck_amt = ($0+0) * 100
     }
     if( $0 ~ /Dollars and/ ) {
          # found check body.
        gsub(/\*\*$/, "", $0)
        if ( pcheck_amt != tab_total) {
         printf"\n   Check # %6d   %s   Sum tab %10.2f Check amount %7.2f\n  %s\
n", check_num, check_date, tab_total/100, pcheck_amt/100, $0
       }
         tab_total=0

     }
}
```

With debugging added:

```
BEGIN{ tab_total = pcheck_amt = 0  }
{
     gsub(/,/, "")
     gsub(/\$/, "")
     gsub(/^M/, "", $0)
     # Find a line with decimal point
     a= index($0,".")
     c= index($0,"/")
            if ( a > 0 && a < 50 ) {
#print "a = ",a,"   ", $0
               for( i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                  b = index($i,".")
print "b = ",b,"   ", $0
                  if( b > 0 ) {
print "before Tab total= ", tab_total
                      tab_total+= ($i * 100)
print "after Tab total= ", tab_total
                  }
              }

            }
     # Find the date line
     if ( c > 50 ) {
        check_num = $1
        check_date = $2
        if( NF > 2 ) who_to = $3
     }
     # Find the printed check amount
     if ( a > 50  ) {
print "a= ",a,"  ",$1
         pcheck_amt = ($1+0) * 100
print "$1 = ", $1,"  *100 =  ", (($1+0) * 100 )
     }
#print $0
     if( $0 ~ /Dollars and/ ) {
          # found check body.
        gsub(/\*\*$/, "", $0)
printf "RAW tab_total    %d  format %%d\n", tab_total
printf "RAW pcheck_amt   %d  format %%d\n", pcheck_amt
printf "RAW pcheck_amt   %f  format %%f\n", pcheck_amt
printf "RAW pcheck_amt/100   %d format %%d\n", pcheck_amt/100
printf "tab_total - pcheck_amt   %f\n", tab_total - pcheck_amt
printf "pcheck_amt - tab_total   %f\n",  pcheck_amt  - tab_total

        if (( tab_total - pcheck_amt)  == 0 ) print "true"
        if ( pcheck_amt != tab_total) {
         printf"\n   Check # %6d   %s   Sum tab %10.2f Check amount %7.2f\n  %s\
n", check_num, check_date, tab_total/100, pcheck_amt/100, $0
       }
         tab_total=0

     }
}
```

And the output of the check above

```
# cat check63282 | gawk -f bbprint_scan.awk
b =  0       99820989      20220616       326.10
b =  0       99820989      20220616       326.10
b =  4       99820989      20220616       326.10
before Tab total=  0
after Tab total=  32610
b =  0       Discount                      -3.26
b =  3       Discount                      -3.26
before Tab total=  32610
after Tab total=  32284
a=  74    322.84
$1 =  322.84   *100 =   32284
RAW tab_total    32284  format %d
RAW pcheck_amt   32283  format %d
RAW pcheck_amt   32284.000000  format %f
RAW pcheck_amt/100   322 format %d
tab_total - pcheck_amt   0.000000    format %f
pcheck_amt - tab_total   -0.000000    format %f
tab_total - pcheck_amt   7.275958e-12    format %e
pcheck_amt - tab_total   -7.275958e-12    format %e

   Check #  63282   06/21/2022   Sum tab     322.84 Check amount  322.84
    Three Hundred Twenty Two Dollars and 84 Cents******************************
#
```

Comment: On a brief glance, without reading much of the code, aren't you comparing floating point numbers to zero?  Shouldn't you convert all amounts to int(cents)?

Answer (score 0):

side note :

```
  gsub(/^M/, "")     # strip DOS line ending
```

`^M` is what some apps use to visual the invisible byte `\r`, but when u directly try to use that in a `regex`, what it actually ends up doing is stripping an `ASCII` capital letter `M` whenever it's the first letter in the entire line.

if u wanna deal with line endings, do this instead

- `RS = "\r?\n"    # preferred`

> or

- `sub("\15$", "")`